# Acessar valores setados no Controoller no Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, url, cookies, e-commerce

Estou setando o valor do cookie no FrontControlller:

```
this->context->cookie->utm_campaign = $_GET['utm_campaign'];
```

Porém ao acessar no OrderConfirmationControllerCore está vindo nulo:

```
$this->context->cookie->utm_campaign;
```

Também já tentei e continua vindo vazio:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('utm_campaign', $this->context->cookie->utm_campaign);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema criando um cookie por jscript ao invés de utilizar do prestashop. Outro problema que identifiquei foi que o Chrome não cria cookies de localhost, somente no Edge consegui testar.